# Can I say like this in this situation?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

I think “I saw that a bear was jumping with joy” is wrong because joy can’t be seen. Am I right? That-clause is a whole object of the verb, and all the meaning of the clause should be seen, as I know.

Comment: [ correction: Can I say X like Y?] jump for joy is an idiomatic expression and whatever you think the bear was doing is whatever **you** think and not for us to tell you.

Comment: Jumping for joy is a common English phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you are wrong. You may not technically be able see the neurophysiological changes that create emotions such as joy, but you can see the effects they produce, such as a smile, a frown, or tears. In this case, the joy manifests itself as *jumping*. The jumping is visible evidence of the joy.

Consider an example: you can't see wind, but you *can* see the effect of wind on other things. So, you might say "I can see the wind blowing the trees". You aren't saying that you can see the wind, but you are saying that you can see the trees moving, and recognise that the wind is making them move.